# No message when downvoting

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I just down voted an answer and didn't get a "Please leave a comment..." message. I then issued a down vote on the question just to check and didn't get a message there either.

The question is located [here](https://superuser.com/questions/126212/in-google-chrome-using-ubuntu-is-there-any-way-to-map-a-single-key-to-close-tab/126233#126233).

Also note that it appears that "please" should be capitalized in the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only appears if you have less than 2000 reputation.

It's assumed that when you reach 2000 you will have learned that it's polite to explain your downvote with a comment.

Comment: He's at 3.7k on SU (where the problem occurred) so that seems unlikely, unless he rarely downvotes...

Comment: @Polly: What do you mean "seems unlikely"? High rep users never get that message (try downvoting here on meta or on stack overflow) and low rep users always do (try on super user since your rep is low there). I don't remember what X is but it's surely lower than the OP's rep (3.7k), so he indeed shouldn't see that message

Comment: @Kop - Seems unlikely that it was a recent change for him.  Perhaps he rarely downvotes...

Comment: @Polly: +744/-180

Comment: @Jon: That is correct. I don't know if that qualifies as "rarely" but I do one or two a day. Perhaps I haven't noticed?

Comment: @Josh: No idea for SU, as I don't post there. I just wanted to put the +/- numbers here so there's no need to guess.

Comment: it is 1000 on meta btw, but 2000 everywhere else.

Comment: @Jeff I preferred the mystery of X reputation....